# Why append slice in Go change the original slice?

Tags: go, append, slice

I have this code:

```
// The input param is A := []int{3, 4, 5, 3, 7}
func someFunc(A []int) int {   
...
    ways := 0       
    i := 0
    for i < len(A) {
        if i+1 == len(A) || i == len(A) {
            fmt.Println("break")
            break
        }
        tempA := A // copy the slice by value

        fmt.Println("A: ", A)
        fmt.Println("tempA: ", A)
        fmt.Println()

        newArr = remove(tempA, i)

        if isAesthetic(newArr) {
            ways++
        }
        i++
    }
...
}

func remove(slice []int, s int) []int {
    return append(slice[:s], slice[s+1:]...)
}
```

Cosole output:

```
A:  [3 4 5 3 7]
tempA:  [3 4 5 3 7]

A:  [4 5 3 7 7]
tempA:  [4 5 3 7 7]

A:  [4 3 7 7 7]
tempA:  [4 3 7 7 7]

A:  [4 3 7 7 7]
tempA:  [4 3 7 7 7]
```

The variable `A` also changes while I just copy it by value into `tempA`. And also it is `append()` function, why the slice that used to append `tempA` also changed?

Comment: `tempA := A` does not copy a slice by value; it makes `tempA` point to the same contents as `A`, so modifying the contents `tempA` also modifies `A`

Comment: @EliBendersky This https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-copy-an-array-into-another-array-in-golang/ reference is a scam then. So how to make it copy by value? So the `A` doesn't change when `tempA` change.

Comment: A slice is a view of an array. Slices are not arrays. Assigning an array copies the array. Assigning a slice copies the slice header not the contents of it.

Comment: @alramdein See the copy section in [slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#copy).

Comment: All data types in Go have a static size. If it doesn't have a constant number of elements, it's not an array. Slices are also statically sized, because the real data isn't stored "inside" the value (hence your issue).

Comment: @alramdein: a slice variable is just a header (containing three elements: location of backing array if any, current length, and capacity). Using `tempA := A` copies the *slice header*, but does nothing with the backing array. The two slice headers now both use the same backing array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to utilize the `copy` function:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   a := []int{3, 4, 5, 3, 7}
   // bad
   b := a
   // good
   c := make([]int, len(a))
   copy(c, a)
   // CHANGES b and a!
   b = append(b[:1], b[2:]...)
   // c stays the same, a is messed up
   // [3 5 3 7 7] [3 5 3 7] [3 4 5 3 7]
   fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/builtin#copy

Comment: The result of this is exactly like what I wanted to. I already use `copy()` to solve this, but I miss the point that I need to initialize it first with the same *length* of the slice that I want to copy. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A slice variable of type `[]T`, also called slice header, describes a contiguous section of a backing array. It is *stored separately* from the array data.

You can imagine it as a struct containing the length and a pointer to a certain item of the array (not necessarily the first one).

When you assign the value of a slice variable, you are actually assigning the length and pointer held by the slice header. So `tempA` ends up referencing the same backing array as `A`. Then indexing either will access the same underlying array item.

Recommended reading: https://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 3):

The type `[]T` is a `slice` with elements of type `T`. What is a `slice`, then?

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).

[image: Slice]

The rectangle on left is the slice descriptor. The descriptor has 3 fields i.e., a pointer to the array, length, and capacity of array segment it is pointing to. Now, the pointer is pointing to a backing array on the right that actually stores the elements.

Suppose, you have a slice:

```
x := make([]byte, 5, 5)
```

Then it'd point to a backing array `[5]byte` as you can also see in the image.

Now, if you do:

```
y := x
```

thinking that would copy, but it wouldn't. It'd just create a new slice descriptor pointing to the same backing array that `x` was pointing to.

Hence, there's a built-in called [copy](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) which would help you copy (exactly what you want)

```
The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a destination slice.
```

With `copy` you also get a new backing array that your destination site is pointing to.

To know more about slices, read [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This answer almost perfect for me, but there is a point I miss that other user already answer it. Thank you.